# Returning dynamic image from action method using Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an action method that dynamically generates a captcha image and returns as a binary file. On my view page, I am able to get the captcha displayed when the page loads. I also have a refresh link that calls the action method to get a new captcha image using $.ajax which is not displaying a new captcha image when clicked. The $.jax call is successfully made but the binary file is not getting displayed. I want to display the new image without reloading the whole page when the refresh link is clicked.

Am I missing something or is there another way to call the action method without refreshing the page using jquery. Any help would be appreciated. Below is my code

// Action method that generates the image

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        public FileContentResult CaptchaImage(bool noisy = true)
        {
            var rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

            //generate new question
            int a = rand.Next(10, 99);
            int b = rand.Next(0, 9);
            var captcha = string.Format("{0} + {1} = ?", a, b);

            //store answer
            Session["Captcha"] = a + b;

            //image stream
            FileContentResult img = null;

            using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
            using (var bmp = new Bitmap(130, 30))
            using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bmp))
            {
                gfx.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
                gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));

                //add noise
                if (noisy)
                {
                    int i, r, x, y;
                    var pen = new Pen(Color.Yellow);
                    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        pen.Color = Color.FromArgb(
                        (rand.Next(0, 255)),
                        (rand.Next(0, 255)),
                        (rand.Next(0, 255)));

                        r = rand.Next(0, (130 / 3));
                        x = rand.Next(0, 130);
                        y = rand.Next(0, 30);

                        gfx.DrawEllipse(pen, x - r, y - r, r, r);
                    }
                }

                //add question
                gfx.DrawString(captcha, new Font("Tahoma", 15), Brushes.Gray, 2, 3);

                //render as Png
                bmp.Save(mem, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                img = this.File(mem.GetBuffer(), "image/png");
            }

            return File(img.FileContents, img.ContentType);
        }

}
```

// View page that calls the action method to display captcha

```
<a id="GetCaptcha" href="javascript:void(0)">Refresh</a>
<img id="CaptchaImg" alt="Captcha" src="@Url.Action("CaptchaImage")" style="" />

@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#GetCaptcha').click(function () {                

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url:  '@Url.Action("CaptchaImage")', 
                    contentType: "image/png",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Success"); // For testing
                        $('#CaptchaImg').attr('src', "data:image/png;base64," + data);
                    },
                   error: function(error, txtStatus) {
                            console.log(txtStatus);
                            console.log('error');
                        }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action method is not generating a base64 encoded string, it's creating a full file response.

So to refresh the captcha image, you won't need to update the source on the existing image, instead create a new `<img src="/home/captchaimage?randomString">` element and replace the existing captcha image with it.

Caching will most likely be an issue so you will need to generate a unique string to append to the path, something like a random number or the current date time so each request is unique.

Otherwise you alter your action method to return a base64 string, then alter the `<img src="@Url.Action..` in the view to be `<img src="data:image/png;base64,@Html.Action(...` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks Brent, for your reply. Your suggestion worked for me. Thanks again.